# How to reload a WWW class?

Tags: c#, web-services, unity-game-engine

I have a  WWW class, which is created every time whenever **GetData** function is called with the same url.

Now when I run it, the first time **GetData** function is calling the url which is being requested (i have a breakpoint in the webservice).
Then the other times Get Data is called and the WWW instanciated, it is filled with the data without making the request (my breakpoint in the service is not being hit.).

But I would like to make a new call every time GetData is called. (To poll the webservice)

How would I enable such behaviour? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

```
  void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating("GetData", 1.0f, 1.0f);   
    }

void GetData()
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(url);

        while (!www.isDone && string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
        }    

        www.Dispose();    
    }
```

Comment: Its not my WWW class it´s unity´s. And the loop is not the problem. I testet by putting a break point before the loop and it gets hit multiple times.

Comment: Did you ever check if there's anything in `www.error`. Try to set a breakpoint at `www.Dispose` and see if there's anything in that.

Comment: www.error is always null

Comment: But are you sure the issue is not on the server? Your code (tho containing a bit of issue) does not reuse the same WWW object. Somehow, it gets the data but may not hit the breakpoint for any reason on the server.

Comment: @Everts I am sure! My server is just giving a string back without doing anything with it (1liner) and I have the breakpoint in the first row!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that somehow the data was being cashed.
I solved the problem like this:

```
WWW www = new WWW(url + "?t=" + Random.value);
```

This way each time I create a new WWW I also create a new request by using a 
different url (still calling the same function).

It would be better to turn off cashing for a WWW request altogether. But this works too.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using coroutine properly. Actually, your snippet is commonly regarded as wrong implementation. You get the program stuck in the loop until it is done.

```
void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating("GetData", 1.0f, 1.0f);   
}

void GetData()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetDataCoroutine())    
}
IEnumerator GetDataCoroutine()
{
     WWW www = new WWW(url);
     yield return www;  
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error) == false){ Debug.Log(www.error); } 
     www.Dispose();  
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Your code is better but it is not solving my problem.